# ADODB.Connection #424: Object required

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Sorry too many questions to look thru.
My code:

```
Function GetConnection(ByVal Server, ByVal Database, ByVal UserID, ByVal Password)
    Dim conn
    On Error Resume Next
    Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set conn = Nothing
        Response.Write "#" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        Response.End
        Exit Function
    End If
    CONST connStringFormat = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=@Password;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=@UserID;Initial Catalog=@Database;Data Source=@Server"
    Dim myConnectionString
    myConnectionString = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(connStringFormat, "@Server", Server), "@Database", Database), "@UserID", UserID), "@Password", Password)

    conn.Open myConnectionString
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set GetConnection = conn
End Function
```

The returned error as seen on my webpage is:

> #424: Object required

Any ideas what is causing this? Please ignore the fact I am not checking for correct connectonstring the point is it bombs out on the `Server.CreateObject("...")` statement!

Comment: If you showed a [mcve] it would help at the moment you are not showing how you are using `GetConnection()` in your code to instantiate an `ADODB.Connection` object.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at my code a thousand times and stepping away I took my CreateObject call out of the function and it worked (why, why, why) i.e. I turned my function into a sub and used a global variable.

```
Sub SetupConnection(ByVal Server, ByVal Database, ByVal UserID, ByVal Password)
    CONST connStringFormat = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=@Password;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=@UserID;Initial Catalog=@Database;Data Source=@Server"

    Dim myConnectionString
    myConnectionString = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(connStringFormat, "@Server", Server), "@Database", Database), "@UserID", UserID), "@Password", Password)

    conn.Open myConnectionString
End Sub

Dim conn
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
SetupConnection ...
```

Comment: You didn't show how you where using the `GetConnection()` function to instantiate the `ADODB.Connection`. My guess is you weren't doing this *(before you change it to a `Sub`)* `Set MyConnObject = GetConnection("...", "...", "...", "...")`.

Comment: Your guess is correct. So what is your point? You have not given me your solution where to fix it! Do I need to use 'Set' in some cases and not in others??

Comment: Without seeing how you were initially calling the `GetConnection()` function in the originally question *(not just the function definition)* I would just be guessing which is why I haven't posted a solution.

Comment: My point is what alternative way can you call it other than what you described. If there is no alternative way then this is implied. I know in some cases, do not quote me, you can call just X = funcY(), i.e. the Set is not required if the function returns an object and the set is inside the function. I am just guessing at this stage without trying.

Comment: We are just going round in circles if you post in the question how you are calling `GetConnection()`, show the code that you tried to run we might get somewhere.

Comment: I have already told you in fact twice if you read between the lines what part of "Your guess is correct." don't you understand and what part of "what alternative way can you call it" without getting a syntax error (implied) can you call it. I am not trying to be facetious I am generally asking you is there something you know that I do not know how to call this function?

Comment: I get what you are saying now, in VB you have default field settings so without the Set you get the default setting which may be the ConnectionString property as supposed to the Connection object which I wanted. I can assure you I used the Set and it gave me the run time error as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there is nothing wrong with the approach  just how it's called *(bit of an assumption as I haven't seen any calling code)*.

While error handling is a good thing currently the `On Error Resume Next` isn't very useful and only captures issues with instantiating a `ADODB.Connection` object which is not going to happen often.

```
Function GetConnection(ByVal Server, ByVal Database, ByVal UserID, ByVal Password)
    Dim conn: Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Const connStringFormat = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=@Password;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=@UserID;Initial Catalog=@Database;Data Source=@Server"
    Dim myConnectionString: myConnectionString = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(connStringFormat, "@Server", Server), "@Database", Database), "@UserID", UserID), "@Password", Password)

    'You are more likely to get errors here, when trying to open the connection.
    Call conn.Open(myConnectionString)
    Set GetConnection = conn
    Set conn = Nothing
End Function
```

To call this correctly you still need to use the `Set` statement so that the new Object is instantiated correctly.

For example this will work

```
Dim conn: Set conn = GetConnection("YourServer", "YourDatabase", "YourUserName", "YourPassword")
```

But this will fail because the `ADODB.Connection` object assumes we want the default string representation which will be the `ConnectionString`.

```
Dim conn: conn = GetConnection("YourServer", "YourDatabase", "YourUserName", "YourPassword")
```

To prove that here is a quick test

```
Dim conn: conn = GetConnection("YourServer", "YourDatabase", "YourUserName", "YourPassword")
Call Response.Write("conn is " & TypeName(conn) & "<br />")

Set conn = GetConnection("YourServer", "YourDatabase", "YourUserName", "YourPassword")
Call Response.Write("conn is " & TypeName(conn) & "<br />")
```

Output:

```
conn is String
conn is Connection
```

Comment: I think you are missing my point or stating the obvious as I see it. Please note I only added the On Error code as an after thought when receiving the error I just placed the On Error in the location as in my question above just to emphasize at what the line was at error and I narrowed down to this line. The point of my question was not my intention to write proper error checking code in this manner or in fact have it at all. Unless I have a typo somewhere my original code is essentially the same as yours but I am saying it doesn't work!

Comment: It is bit like that game you play as a kid spot the 10 differences in the adjacent pictures. This is the same thing I am doing something obviously dumb and I can't see it